# Using Fira with Metropolis / Miktex Windows

Tags: beamer, fonts, miktex, beamer-metropolis

I'm trying to use the [Metropolis](https://github.com/matze/mtheme) theme for Beamer. I'm running a `MikTeX` (portable) distribution on my windows machine.

My problem is with the `Fira Sans` font. I installed the package `fira` using the `MikTeX` package manager, but when I use the command `pdflatex` to compile my presentation I don't see that font used like the presentation from the demo.

Comment: If you want to use the fira fonts, don't compile with pdflatex, but with lualatex or xelatex. The metropolis theme should give you a warning with this instructions in the .log file.

Comment: Did you use `\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}`?

Comment: @samcarter: Why should someone not use `pdflatex` with the Fira font??

Comment: @Herbert Metropolis uses the fire font as default IF compiled with xe/lualatex (not when compiled with pdflatex). So the easiest solution to use fira fonts is to not compile with pdflatex, because then fire fonts will automatically be used and one does not need to do anything.

Comment: I used `Fira` font, I don't face any issues using all `TeX` engines, working fine...

Answer (score 1):

The metropolis theme will automatically use fira fonts if the document is compiled with XeLatex/LuaLatex instead of pdflatex.